# Xcode9: Fix All In Scope is always disabled

Tags: xcode, xcode9

Xcode9: Editor- Fix All In Scope is always disabled

How can I enable it ?

Comment: Seeing the same issue with xcode 9 GM. Probably a bug.

Comment: If it is a bug since beta version it should definitely be fixed. I migrating my project to Swift 4 and I got over 1000 errors. Im not going to fix all of them one by one.

Comment: Reported bug to Apple. Will tell you when they answer.

Comment: @MateuszWlodarczyk any news on this? This is so frustating. Even with the very newest xCode (no beta) I got this problem.

Comment: @J.Doe No. No reply from Apple so far. I never issued any bug to Apple, so I don´t know what is the usual time of reply. Maybe somebody who has some experience in that matter could tell us?

Comment: I´ve got info in the Apple Bug Report that my case duplicates the other: DUPLICATE OF 32432839 OPEN. No further details provided...

Comment: The same issue happens still in 9.1 beta (9B37).

Comment: xCode 9.0.1 released 16 oct. Still the same issue. What are they doing there? I really mis the old xCode in which you did not had to double tap that red circle in order to fix it. Earlier, you had the button 'fix' right away. @MateuszWlodarczyk any news?!

Answer (score 1):

Updated in new Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b), works like charm :)