# Xcode 9 - Fix all in Scope greyed out

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

With Xcode 8 the errors could be fixed using the "Fix all in Scope", but in the latest Xcode 9 that option is always greyed out. Do you have an idea if I have to set up something or if it's just a bug?

[image: code with error]

[image: Xcode menu]

The Xcode I'm using is the App Store version, build number 9A235, so it's not a beta.

Comment: Is it a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916484/xcode9-beta2-fix-all-in-scope-is-always-disabled?

Comment: It's not. I'm not talking about a beta version.

Comment: Unfortunately it look like a bug, moreover know issue. In the comments you can read that someone raise it to the Apple and Apple mark as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916484/xcode9-beta2-fix-all-in-scope-is-always-disabled

Comment: some news from the feature!
it's completely fixed in early versions of Xcode but new bugs appeared! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it helps to clean "derived data", the project and to restart your mac. Feels like Windows but I have good experiences with this kind of bugs.

Navigate to the deived data folder in Finder. For this open tab Locations in XCode Settings where you will find a link. Delete all data within derived data folder. (No worry - it will be restored by XCode)

Comment: How do you clean?

Comment: @DaniSpringer 
Press "cmd + shift + k" all together

Comment: That "clean" shortcut empties the derived data folder? Never knew that... Thank you! @byJeevan

Comment: @user5306470 No it doesn't. Derived Data need to be deleted manually (or via a script)

Answer (score 1):

look for and select the page you have error and there is the word **fix**
[image]

and go **Editor**  >>>> Fix All Issues

Comment: Doesn't help at all

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem multiple times! Occasionally, it occurs when there are multiple solutions to rectify an error. Once you identify the error and select a solution, the "Fix All In Scope" feature will be reactivated.